# Why can't I push HEAD^ to origin without specifying a branch?

Tags: git, bitbucket, ubuntu-18.04

In my feature branch:

```
$ git push origin HEAD
Counting objects: 6, done.
...
```

But:

```
$ git push origin HEAD^
fatal: remote part of refspec is not a valid name in HEAD^
```

Why do I need to specify the branch (unlike with plain `HEAD`):

```
$ git push origin HEAD^:my_branch
Everything up-to-date
```

Comment: doesn't `git push origin my_branch` itself work?

Comment: `git push origin HEAD^:my_branch` is like `scp HEAD^ origin/my_branch`. Without `:my_branch`, git has to take a guess of what the target is. If the target can't be inferred from gitconfig or anywhere else, it errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See `git help push`. Normally, the *refspec* argument has two parts separated by a colon. The colon and destination ref can be omitted:

> If git `push [<repository>]` without any `<refspec>` argument is set to update some ref at the destination with `<src>` with `remote.<repository>.push` configuration
>              variable, `:<dst>` part can be omitted—such a push will update a ref that `<src>` normally updates without any `<refspec>` on the command line. Otherwise, missing
>              `:<dst>` means to update the same ref as the `<src>`.

But, `HEAD^` is not configured to update any ref and doesn't exist yet on the remote, so git doesn't know which remote ref to update with it.